# Ckeditor5 htmlSupport UL classes to li

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve but can't find the cause.i am using ckeditor5 i have problem when i try to add html classes via editor

```
<ul class="test">
    <li>twsafs</li>
    <li>twsafs</li>
    <li>twsafs</li>
    <li>twsafs</li>
</ul>
```

i want to use it like this but the editor is rendering as below

```
<ul>
    <li class="test">
        twsafs
    </li>
    <li class="test">
        twsafs
    </li>
    <li class="test">
        twsafs
    </li>
    <li class="test">
        twsafs
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out the reason, if you can help I would be glad

I tried to allow all classes with htmlSupport but no change.
[i try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgXzx.png)

Comment: Do you really want to go down this rabbit hole? CKEditor uses a [editing engine](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html). You can change the Schema it uses.

Comment: I looked it up, but it was very confusing to me, can you help me in another way?